# Why does exiting Python REPL clear my Ctrl-V Bash mapping?

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I have mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> in my `.bash_profile` to a function that opens a file in Vim using fzf. It works perfectly, but whenever I exit from the Python REPL the mapping doesn't work until I source my `.bash_profile` **twice** or start a completely new shell session.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Use this minimal `.bash_profile` that replicates the problem:

   ```
   stty lnext ^-
   bind -x '"\C-v": "echo mapping works"'
   ```
2. Start a Bash session.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> -> see the output `mapping works`.
4. Run `python3`.
5. Use `exit()` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to exit the REPL.
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> is back to its default behavior.
7. `source ~/.bash_profile` the mapping still doesn't work?
8. `source ~/.bash_profile` now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> correctly produces `mapping works`, how?

Why does starting/exiting the Python REPL affect my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> mapping (this does not happen to my other mappings)? And why do I need to source my profile twice for the mapping to start working?

---

Here's example output of running `stty -a | grep lnext`:

```
~ $ stty -a | grep lnext
    lnext = <undef>; min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q;
~ $ python3
Python 3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18)
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
~ $ stty -a | grep lnext
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
~ $ source ~/.bash_profile
~ $ stty -a | grep lnext
    lnext = <undef>; min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q;
~ $ source ~/.bash_profile
~ $ stty -a | grep lnext
    lnext = <undef>; min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q;
```

---

Here is some information of my system, `python3` is from python.org's installer, and `bash` is from Homebrew:

```
~ $ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
~ $ python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
~ $ which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
~ $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
~ $ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.5
BuildVersion:   19F101
```

---

Here is even more information about my system:

```
~ $ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.0.17(1)-release
~ $ lsof -p $$
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF                NODE NAME
bash    78982 eero  cwd    DIR    1,5     1568              359056 /Users/eero
bash    78982 eero  txt    REG    1,5   991320             4660332 /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.17/bin/bash
bash    78982 eero  txt    REG    1,5  1568368 1152921500312627066 /usr/lib/dyld
bash    78982 eero    0u   CHR   16,2   0t3107                 985 /dev/ttys002
bash    78982 eero    1u   CHR   16,2   0t3107                 985 /dev/ttys002
bash    78982 eero    2u   CHR   16,2   0t3107                 985 /dev/ttys002
bash    78982 eero  255u   CHR   16,2   0t3107                 985 /dev/ttys002
~ $ /usr/local/bin/bash -li
~ $
```

Comment: so what is the output of `stty -a | grep lnext` after exiting from python and after the first and second sourcing of `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I dont know why it is occuring. But I am giving a turnaround. Create a new `alias` - `exit_2` which will `exit` as well as `source ~/.bash_profile` twice.

Comment: @binarysta Edited that in :)

Comment: seems after exit of python repl, `stty sane` is being running, but I don't know why :-/

Comment: The problem is not reproducible on my system: Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8.2, `BASH_VERSION=5.0.16(1)-release`. Perhaps some system file is sourced when the repl starts and/or exits (`grep -l 'stty'` ~/.??*`) ? Or `env | grep PYTHON` ?

Comment: @michael Could it be a macOS issue then?

Comment: I can try later on a mac, but if that's the case, it could either be a bash or python version/distro issue... To help others also trouble-shooting, which version & distro of `bash` are you using (the default macOS `bash`, or macports/homebrew?); and which python (eg conda/brew/python.org)?

Comment: @michael Added information about my system.

Comment: Thanks. Tried my mac, and (initially!) did NOT see the problem, using `$BASH_VERSION=5.0.11(1)-release` and python 3.7.5 (macOS 10.15.5). I'm using macports, btw, so my `bash` is `/opt/local/bin/bash`. However, if I use the macOS default `/bin/bash`, version `3.2.57(1)-release`, then I get _exactly_ the behavior you describe (including needing to source `.bash_profile` twice). One thing about your version info: can you check `echo $BASH_VERSION` and (if you have `lsof`), run `lsof -p $$` to verify you're not running the older bash? Also, compare to explicitly running `/usr/local/bin/bash -li`

Comment: ps: since I share my dot-files across linux & mac, I also created a new user account on ubuntu, with default dot-files, and the problem did not occur. I'm leaning towards it being a mac-specific issue, possibly with the older default software that comes w/ macOS, vs the newer gnu versions that come w/ homebrew, macports, etc.

Comment: @michael Added the outputs of those to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Isaac's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592618/337515) was correct and worked just fine, but in the end the solution was even simpler. I could just remove the whole `stty lnext ...` line from my `.bash_profile` and then the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> mapping works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I can not reproduce the problem that leaving REPL python changes lnext.
But I can confirm that you need to source a file twice to get the bind key to work (the output of `mapping works`).

Note that you need to start a **logging** bash session to get `.bash_profile` to be read. A file like:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
echo bash_profile read
#stty lnext ^-
stty lnext ''
```

Will only work if bash is called like `bash -l` for example. Just check that you get `bash_profile read` when you start bash.

## Solution:

The best bet is to set the key binding in the file `~/.inputrc`:

```
$ cat ~/.inputrc
#bind -x '"\C-v": "echo mapping works"'
\C-v: "echo mapping works\C-m"
```

Then, the binding could be read in with `Ctrl-x Ctrl-r`, nothing else is needed, as soon as that is executed the key binding works in bash. And, it will be read when bash start.

If you still need to remove the **same** keybinding in the tty:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
echo bash_profile read
#stty lnext ^-
stty lnext ''
```

Using `lnext ''` works more consistently IME. Remove or comment the echo when needed.

**Added**
There is no way to (exactly) mimic the `bind -x` way of executing **shell** commands.

But what is a command ?, but an string that ends with an enter.
Place this on the `~/.inputrc`

```
\C-v: "echo 'yes\!. It works.'\n"
```

Re-read the `~/.inputrc` file and try `\C-v`.
Note that (IME) it is better to use `\C-m`.

If you want the line cleared before typing the command, use

```
\C-v: "\C-e\C-x\C-?echo 'yes\!. It works.'\C-m\C-y"
```

But, bear in mind that more complex bindings have more probability to fail for unknown reasons. Just try it, maybe it will work for you. If it does, the only difference with the normal `bind -x` is that the command executed gets into the history (nothing important IMhO).

Related:

- [Shell Tricks: .inputrc binding fun](https://brettterpstra.com/2015/07/09/shell-tricks-inputrc-binding-fun/)
- [In bash, how do I bind a function key to a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command#4201274)

Comment: I unfortunately can't put the mapping to .inputrc, since in reality the mapping is a `bind -x` mapping which is calling a function I have defined in my .bash_profile.

Comment: `stty lnext ''` THANK YOU! Using that, instead of `stty lnext ^_` in my .bash_profile fixed the issue!

Comment: Sorry forgot to award the bounty

Comment: @ruohola Yes, you did!. But you can always start and award another bounty if you want.

Comment: Well fuck it, I will do that, bye bye all rep :D

Comment: I meant my comment only to be a funny reminder. :-). I did not meant to ask you to give up your reputation points, not at all, sorry. But, on the bright side, thanks for the 100 points, yes, that more than compensate for anything I expected to receive from answering your question. Thanks.

Comment: :D all good man.

Comment: Enjoy the +100 :)

Comment: Yes!, Many thanks, I am as happy as you are for giving them!. @ruohola

Comment: Hmm, it actually seems that `stty lnext ...` wasn't needed at all, my binding seems to work just fine without it.